# Specify number of processes for eventlet wsgi server

Tags: python, flask, socket.io, swagger, eventlet

I am trying to add websocket functionality to an existing application. The existing structure of the app is

In `/server/__init__.py`:

```
from connexion import App
...
connexion_app = App(__name__, specification_dir='swagger/')  # Create Connexion App
app = connexion_app.app  # Configure Flask Application
...
connexion_app.add_api('swagger.yaml', swagger_ui=True)  # Initialize Connexion api
```

In `startserver.py`:

```
from server import connexion_app

connexion_app.run(
    processes=8,
    debug=True
)
```

In this way, I was able to specify the number of processes. There are some long-running tasks that make it necessary to have as many processes as possible.

I have modified the application to include websocket functionality as below. It seems to be that I only have one process available. Once the application attempts to run one of the long-running processes, all API calls hang. Also, if the long-runnign process fails, the application is stuck in a hanging state

In `/server/__init__.py`:

```
from connexion import App
import socketio
...
connexion_app = App(__name__, specification_dir='swagger/')  # Create Connexion App
sio = socketio.Server()  # Create SocketIO for websockets
app = connexion_app.app  # Configure Flask Application
...
connexion_app.add_api('swagger.yaml', swagger_ui=True)  # Initialize Connexion api
```

In `startserver.py`:

```
import socketio
import eventlet

from server import sio
from server import app

myapp = socketio.Middleware(sio, app)
eventlet.wsgi.server(eventlet.listen(('', 5000)), myapp)
```

What am I missing here?

(side note: If you have any resources available to better understand the behemoth of the `Flask` object, please point me to them!!)

Comment: I'm havin similar hanging issues, did you solve it somehow?

Answer (score 1):

- Exact answer to question: Eventlet built-in WSGI does not support multiple processes.
- Approach to get the best solution for described problem: share one file that contains absolute minimum code required to reproduce problem. Maybe here https://github.com/eventlet/eventlet/issues or any other way you prefer.
- Way of hope. Random stuff to poke at: `eventlet.monkey_patch()`, isolate Eventlet and long blocking calls in separate threads or processes.